# How to use nodejs in google firebase hosting service?

Tags: json, firebase

I want to create a nodejs app, but when I tried to create an app with google's hosting firebase I only can modify an index.html file, but I can't use a `index.js` file as a nodejs app.
I don't know how to do with this.
Here is the `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "database":{"rules":"database.rules.json"},
  "hosting":
  {
    "public":"public",
    "rewrites": 
    [{
      "source":"**",
      "destination":"/index.html"
    }]
  }
}
```

But I can't modify that file for executing a nodejs app. Any help?

Comment: FYI this is now possible! Updated my answer below.

Comment: Sorry my arrogancy and videos against google.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It is now possible to host Node.js apps in Firebase Hosting through an integration with Cloud Functions launched in May of 2017. See [Connecting Cloud Functions to Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) docs for more information.

Comment: Thanks for worring about your viewers, but I created a firebase proyect and this is not responding. Should I open a new question that shows the problem?

Comment: They have read-only filesystem, though. Not sure how is that different from a static web page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

FYI>>

Firebase is not only for static node js applications, but it also can be used for dynamic node js applications,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions  -- refer this for more details

and we need to create an object for an app and make it export as follows and replace firebase.json as follows

var app = express();
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

firebase.json:

"rewrites": 
    [{
      "source":"**",
      "destination":"app"
    }]

Answer (score -3):

Firebase is only for static node.js applications. If you are developing a static website then it is okay. But if your webapp contains lot of data processing on the server side you should not use firebase.
You can use xervo hosting. 
[xervo.io](http://xervo.io)

xervo.io is not existed anymore,

Comment: Sorry, but nodejs isn't free in xervo.io, y prefer to use https://codeanywhere.com/
Yes, it's free, but the problem is that the server sometimes stops and I need to restart the service.

Comment: Xervo.io is free for one month....try it i am hosting my website for free.